# Sequence with sum of digits

Tags: number-sequence

What is the sum of the digits of the numbers $x$ and $y$ in the sequence
$335, 333, x, y, 318, 307, 294, ...$? 
Source: [Handbook of Codes and Sequences with Applications in Communication, Computing and Information Security (Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08N6RMG9C)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like

> the differences between the terms are 2, ?, ?, ?, 11, 13

which looks like

> the primes.

Therefore,

> $x = 330$ and $y = 325$

so the sum of their digits is

> $3 + 3 + 0 + 3 + 2 + 5 = 16$

Comment: Lol beat me to it. I came a little late since I was busy answering another puzzle!

Comment: @PrinceDeepthinker yeah, happens to me as well. As for my puzzle, I'll add a hint later. I'm not sure if you know about the [Follow Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/295232) feature, but it's great for keeping up to date with added hints.